# Trying to get property 'n_cotizacion' of non-object (View:

Tags: php, laravel

estoy haciendo una consulta a SQL que me devuelva el ultimo valor y me lo envíe a la view pero quiero hacer una validación si es que la consulta me devuelve un null se envíe un "1" a la view.

Este es mi controlador:

```
public function obtenerNcoti(){

     $ncoti=DB::table('tb_cotizacions')->select('n_cotizacion')->orderBy('n_cotizacion','desc')->first();

    if($ncoti == null){
        $ncoti=1;
        return view ('cotizacion/cotizacion',compact('ncoti')); 
     }else{
        return view ('cotizacion/cotizacion',compact('ncoti'));  

     } 

}
```

Si la consulta tiene datos no hay problemas, pero si es null me tira el siguiente error:

Trying to get property 'n_cotizacion' of non-object (View: C:\Users\javie\OneDrive\Documentos\Mantenedor 2.0\Mantenedores2\resources\views\cotizacion\cotizacion.blade.php)

Este es mi view:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <small>Cotización N°</small>
    <input name="numero_cotizacion" id="cotizacion_numero" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control" required="" value="{{$ncoti->n_cotizacion}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ncoti debería seguir siendo un objeto pero lo estás convirtiendo a entero

ya sea que lo hagas creando un nuevo modelo de laravel o con un stdClass

```
public function obtenerNcoti(){

$ncoti=DB::table('tb_cotizacions')->select('n_cotizacion')->orderBy('n_cotizacion','desc')->first();

 if($ncoti == null){
    $ncoti= new \stdClass();
    $ncoti->n_cotizacion = 1;
 }
 return view ('cotizacion/cotizacion',compact('ncoti'));  
}
```

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me sirvió!!

Answer (score 3):

El error tiene lógica de ser, por lo siguiente:

- Si la consulta no genera resultados, lo único que estás mandando es un número y esto claramente no es lo mismo que un objeto, por eso cuando tienes la siguiente sintaxis falla:

  ```
  $ncoti->n_cotizacion /*no puedes obtener una propiedad llamada n_cotizacion de un número*/
  ```

Por que *dicho número* no posee propiedades a las cuales puedas acceder.

- Una forma de *lidiar* con esto es en la vista establecer un condicional por medio de la [sintaxis de Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements) que evalúe si lo que trae la variable es o no un objeto, esto lo puedes lograr por medio de la función booleana [`is_object`](https://www.php.net/is_object)

  ```
    @if(!is_object($ncoti))
        {{ $ncoti }} <!-- aqui si es número -->
    @else
        {{ $ncoti->n_cotizacion }} <!-- acá si es un objeto -->
    @endif
  ```

**Comentarios finales**

- Te dejo este ejemplo para que evalúes por medio de código de lo que te hablo en la respuesta:

  ```
    <?php

    $esNumero = 1;

    $esObjeto = (object)["id" => 1, "n_cotizacion" => "345A"];

    print_r(gettype($esNumero));

    print_r(gettype($esObjeto));
  ```

Que nos da esta salida:

> integer 
>  object

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me ayudo a entender el por qué del error :)